# Visual Studio Authoring Extensions / SCOM: Another version of this product is already installed

Tags: visual-studio

I'ma bit stuck. Been using Visual Studio 2013 Community edition forever, to create and edit custom SCOM Management Packs in a local GIT Repository. I downloaded VS2019 (and 2017, just for luck), with a view to start using that, but it won't recognise any of my SCOM (MPPROJ) projects.

I figured I just need to update my version of "System Center Visual Studio Authoring Extensions v1.10.201.0" with the currently available download of "System Center Visual Studio Authoring Extensions v1.4.1.0", but this will not install, with the message "Another versin of this product is already installed. Installation of this version cannot continue. To configure or remove the existing version of this product, use Add/Remove Programs on the Control Panel"

Any attempt to so this, results in "The installed product does not match the installation source(s). Until a matching source is provided or the installed product and source are synchronized, this action cannot be performed" leaving me with a 'Browse' dialog box to find the original MSI"

Not sure what to do.

I currently have VS 2013, VS 2017 and VS 2019 all installed on the server, and both VS 2017 and 2019 will not recognise my SCOM Project files (labels them as 'Incompatible').

How can I continue working on my SCOM MPPROJ files in VS 2017 or 2019??

Comment: Had a bit of progress on this one. Was able to run a "Repair" on System Center Visual Studio Extensions, then remove after this, successfully.

However, having now installed the latest version of the System Center VSAE, none of my SCOM Management Pack projects are being picked up still by either VS2017 / 2019, "Incompatible" and "Application not Installed". The extension does show as enabled VS though. Ughh

Answer (score 0):

Ok, this was a few steps to fixing

1. Ran a repair in Control Panel>Programs & Features on the old VSAE install.
2. Successfully uninstalled VSAE
3. Reinstalled new 1.4.1.0 VSAE (x64) - Wierldy states it's v1.10.218.0 in Programs & Features
4. Existing SCOM Projects unable to open (new or existing) without error "Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.VisualStudio.TemplateWizardInterface..."
5. Opened VS Installer and used 'Modify' to install the 'Modelling SDK' component for VS 2019.
6. New error on SCOM projects:"Expected 1 exports with contract name....microsoft.systemcenter.authoring.presenter.ipresenterservice"
7. Opened VS Installer and ran a More>Repair on VS 2019.
8. Can now create a new SCOM Project, however existing SCOM projects have to be 'Reload'ed in the VS GUI to restore their SCOM MP file structure and remove the "Incompatible" status (Annoying when you have dozens of Projects).

Phew.

It's worth mentioning that before I ran these steps, I DID install MicrosoftProgram_Install_and_Uninstall.meta.diagcab and fed it the Uninstaller regkey GUID for the old VSAE that was installed. It didn't seem to fix anything, but did run a bunch of cleanup activities, so that MAY have also been a contributing factor to this resolution. Worth trying if the Repair doesn't work in first step.